# Android Service does not start

Tags: android, android-service

I trying to add a service to my android app but the service wont start at all. I added it to my android manifest so that it starts in its own process and created a broadcastreceiver which should start the service after the BOOT_COMPLETED.

Here the part of my manifest

```
    <service android:process=":attachServiceBackground"
             android:name=".AttachService"
             android:icon="@drawable/camera"
             android:label="@string/attachServiceName" />

    <receiver android:name="AttachmentStartupReceiver"
                android:process=":attachServiceBackground">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>      
        </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

my service ... just added logging

```
public class AttachService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = AttachService.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate service");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }   
}
```

And my BroadCastReceiver

```
public class AttachmentStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent attachSvc = new Intent(context, AttachService.class);
    context.startService(attachSvc);
}
}
```

I cannot see that the service starts after booting the device, there is no "oncreate service" in the logs and also I looked in the Settings->Applications->Running Services.
Does someone know what I made wrong?

Thanks

Comment: do you have the permission to receive BOOT_COMPLETED ?

Comment: your broadcast receiver has been called?

Comment: No my receiver has not been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't send a broadcast by default.

Comment: I added this, restarted the emulator and redeployed my app on the device, but its still not starting my service. Any other advice?

Comment: Ok, now its running. The permission was missing AND my receiver was not found by android. After I changed the receiver name in the manifest it work. The correct receiver element was          <receiver
            android:name=".AttachmentStartupReceiver"
            android:process=":attachServiceBackground" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>